# Running scripts for Flask in Mac Terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask

I am a total beginner to Flask, and I am studying it using Miguel Grinberg's Flask Mega-Turorial.

On t his page (Hello World), https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world, where do I write this script he has shown:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app import routes
```

Since I was in the Mac terminal for the previous steps, I wrote the code "from flask import Flask" also in terminal but that returned the following error:

`zsh: command not found: from`

Should I be doing everything in VS Code perhaps? He hasn't mentioned about it so far.

Comment: It seems pretty self-explanotary if you read the tutorial. It says you should create a directory/folder and then tells you that a file `__init__.py` should contain those lines.

Comment: What I did was - moved away from the Terminal video, opened the file on VS Code, and then as you said, created the files in question. My question was to clarify where are these scripts written - in terminal or an IDE.

Comment: Usually things written in a terminal will start with either `$` or `#`. When things are meant to be written in the python interpreter (when you just execute `python`) it starts with `>>>`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the following steps:

1. Open VS Code.
2. Create a new folder for your project (e.g., "flask_app").
3. Inside this folder, create a new Python file. You can name it
   `__init__.py`.
4. In this file, write the following code:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app import routes
```

5. Save the file.

You should run Python scripts from the terminal using the `python` command or use Run Python file function provided by python extension, not by typing Python code directly into the terminal.